# Reorganise pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe with this column entitled vehicule with some json inside

```
vehicules
[{'immatriculation': AAAAAA, 'type': 'car}]
[{'immatriculation': 'BBBBBB, 'type': 'truck}, {'immatriculation': 'CCCCCC’, 'type': 'car'}]
[{'immatriculation': DDDDDD, 'type': 'car}]
```

I wanted to transform the column in two columns

```
immatriculation     type
AAAAAA              car
BBBBBB              truck
CCCCCC              car
DDDDDD              car
```

What is the easiest way to do this in python / pandas ?

Comment: Your format is ambiguous, please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 0):

If `vehicules` contain a well-formatted list, you can use `explode` and `json_normalize`:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['vehicules'].explode())

  immatriculation   type
0          AAAAAA    car
1          BBBBBB  truck
2          CCCCCC    car
3          DDDDDD    car
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'vehicules': [[{'immatriculation': 'AAAAAA', 'type': 'car'}],
                      [{'immatriculation': 'BBBBBB', 'type': 'truck'},
                       {'immatriculation': 'CCCCCC', 'type': 'car'}],
                      [{'immatriculation': 'DDDDDD', 'type': 'car'}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
                                           vehicules
0     [{'immatriculation': 'AAAAAA', 'type': 'car'}]
1  [{'immatriculation': 'BBBBBB', 'type': 'truck'...
2     [{'immatriculation': 'DDDDDD', 'type': 'car'}]
```

**Note**: your input data is neither a valid json data nor a valid python structure.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is for the row 1 whereI have several item [{'immatriculation': 'BBBBBB, 'type': 'truck}, {'immatriculation': 'CCCCCC’, 'type': 'car'}] 

I wanted to have all immatriculation and type in a new csv